# How do you say: "Заткнись" for a group of people instead of just one person in Russian?

Tags: значения

In Russian, I know there is a word similar to "Заткнись" but it is used for a group of people instead of just one person. What is it?

Comment: Dear Kэли , while this is not quite an answer to your question, you may find this info somewhat pertinent. The word "Заткнись" has a *very* offensive synonym "Завали ебало". This is not simply conversational or even rude; this is plainy offensive. You may use it only if it is in your plans to provoke a fight.

Answer (score 5):

Заткни́тесь.

Similar examples:

- Учи́сь - учи́тесь
- Дери́сь - дери́тесь
- Кати́сь - кати́тесь

I.e. -те- goes in between the ending (-и)  and the posrfix (-сь).

When -сь is preceded by a consonant (including й), it becomes -ся:

- Оста́нься - оста́ньтесь
- (Не) бо́йся - (не) бо́йтесь
- Отметься - отметьтесь

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use the same word in plural, you actually have two variants.Both are rude.

> **Заткнитесь!** (imperative plural ) and **А ну, заткнулись!**(past plural used for imperative )

But there's still a great variety of synonyms, like **замолкли/замолкните,заглохли**, etc. My favourite one is **Кончай базар!**(used in a singular imperative, but addressed to a group)

Comment: Is it actually past? It could as well be subjunctive with "бы" dropped.

Comment: Joker_vD , very formally you are correct: it looks like the past tense.  In reality, it is an order -- and a pretty rude one. And yes, it is against the rules of grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Russian learners!

It is "Заткнитесь".

Comment: *vicodin*, Welcome to the **Russian Language** site!